# Problem when migrate Sybase Database to Oracle with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I tried to use SQL Developer 19.2.1.247, connect Sybase 15.0 with jtds 1.3.1 successfully. However follow error occur and show in Migration Report when try to migrate the Sybase to Oracle:

```
  <logger>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.MigrationLogResourceBundle</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class> 
  <message>Error:ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYB12ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
: FAILED : Database Migration : FAILED</message>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.logging.LogInfo@62187f8f</param>

</record>
```

Any suggestion on the problem? Or any tools/method that can do the migration from Sybase to Oracle.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed after I grant all permission to the user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO migration_user;
```